# Appcelerator Google SignIn using module Ti.GoogleSignIn

Tags: gmail, titanium, appcelerator, gmail-api, appcelerator-titanium

Using [Ti.GoogleSignIn](https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.GoogleSignIn) module by Hansemann, i am trying to access my google drive. Problem is that the google does not honour the token i am getting from module and i am getting **Error 401 : Unauthorized Invalid credentials**.

On the other hand, if i use the token from Google developer playground, it works as expected.

I am setting the scope in the following way

```
Google.initialize({

clientID : "***********************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com",

scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'] // Scope

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So when using a clientID from the playground, it works in your app? Then your current setup may be incorrect. As the error seems to be thrown for both the Titanium based version and native version (bubbled up), you may receive some more help from the native community as well.